# Codeigniter, Jquery Page Refresh if the User is logged In

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, ajaxform

I have been trying this for a whole day, and I can't quite figure out how to do it.

What I am trying to do is:

If the user submits the log-in form, and if the result is successful (meaning that his account exists, and he gets to log in), then the page should reload/refresh after the user is logged in and should be redirected to the same page.

This is what I have done so far:

In my `custom-functions.js` file, I tried to make a generic function for an AJAX form submit.

```
function AjaxFormSubmit(data){
  return data.ajaxSubmit({
        success: function(output){
            var result = output.split(":::");

            if(result[0] == "error")
            {
                var msg = result[1];
                ErrorNotification(msg);
                return 2;
            }else
            if(result[0] == "warning")
            {
                var msg = result[1];
                WarningNotification(msg);

            }else
            if(result[0]== "alert")
            {
                var msg = result[1];
                AlertNotification(msg);

            }else
            if(result[0]== "success")
            {
                var msg = result[1];
                SuccessNotification(msg);
                return 1;
            }
        },
        error: function(output){
            var msg = 'Some Database Error Occurred';
            ErrorNotification(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

Then this is my log-in form:

```
<form action="ManageUsers/login" id="UserLoginForm" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input id="user_username" placeholder="Username Here" style="margin-bottom: 15px; width:90%;" type="text" name="Username" />
    <input id="user_password" placeholder="Password Here" style="margin-bottom: 15px; width:90%;" type="password" name="Password" />
    <input id="user_remember_me" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" type="checkbox" name="RememberMe" value="1" />
    <label class="string optional" for="user_remember_me"> Remember me</label>

    <input class="btn btn-primary" id="UserLoginBtn" style="clear: left; width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px;" type="button" name="commit" value="Sign In" />
</form>
```

And here is the script in my login form for calling the form submit function..

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function(e){
        $('#UserLoginBtn').click(function(e){
            var UserLoginForm = $('#UserLoginForm');
            var FullURL = '';
            var PathUrl = getAbsolutePath();
            var HashLocation = location.hash;
            var FullURL = PathUrl+HashLocation;
            //window.location.reload(FullURL);
            var result = AjaxFormSubmit(UserLoginForm);
            alert(result.data);
        });
    });

</script>
```

The form is submitting successfully, but how can I reload the page if the success function is called?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try 
header("Location: "url"); in php
window.location = "url"; in js

Comment: as I understand, your form is submitted in any case, because you don't prevent it from submission, just make additionall ajax call when button is clicked, right?

Comment: N.B. in php, the url must be absolute. in `header`

Comment: @kodewrecker
How to use header or any php function when success is called...
I want to execute something when success function is called but i dont want to write that code in generic function. cuz not everytime i want to page refresh..

Comment: @paulitto
How it will gonna help me access the success function from PHP file and lets the page reload if result is true ?

Comment: if(value from variable result that would trigger success){
 window.location.href = 'url';
}else{
alert(the error!)
}

Comment: sorry I missed that you're using third-party plugin for ajax call.
why can't you make page reload inside AjaxFormSubmit when result[0]== "success" ?

Comment: @paulitto
Actually i defined the function AjaxFormSubmit in the .js file for generic use.
If i put page reload inside there then everytime that function will be called the page will be reloaded which i dont want it to do.

Comment: then, can you extend this function with one more argument, like AjaxFormSubmit(data, url), then if this argument is defined, set window.location.href to this url on success

Comment: @paulitto
Yes, this is good idea, but how to see if url is passed or not passed..
I mean will i gonna need to use `if(url.length>0){}`

Comment: you may use `if (typeof url !=="undefined"` or `if (typeof url ==="string"){}`

Comment: @paulitto
Many Many Thanks, Problem Solved with your given solution.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function(e){
        $('#UserLoginBtn').click(function(e){
            var UserLoginForm = $('#UserLoginForm');
            var FullURL = '';
            var PathUrl = getAbsolutePath();
            var HashLocation = location.hash;
            var FullURL = PathUrl+HashLocation;
            //window.location.reload(FullURL);
            var result = AjaxFormSubmit(UserLoginForm);
           if(result == 1){
                 window.location.href = FullURL;
               }  


        });
    });
```

Comment: not gonna work and not wokring cuz `alert(result);` returns `[object][object]` :(